# How to use aws-iot sdk in Cordova

Tags: javascript, aws-iot, apache-cordova

As I am a beginner to Apache Cordova i am to use aws-iot sdk in Cordova android I tried downloading the sdk through npm install aws-Iot sdk and installed it but I am getting an error like:REQUIRE IS NOT DEFINED Please guide in solving this error

Comment: because, that  aws-IoT sdk, is to nodejs.. cordova is different.